# How to assign APR? The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found

Tags: json, rest, jersey

> is there an miss import of my jar file or any configuration regarding my web service?
>   help me i'm new in web services, i'm stuck here.

Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;E:\JAVA PROJECT\eclipse;;.
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:EmployeeService' did not find a matching property.
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 402 ms
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:43 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
    INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
      com.rest.employee.model
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:43 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
    INFO: Root resource classes found:
      class com.rest.employee.model.EmployeeService
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:43 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
    INFO: No provider classes found.
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:43 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
    Oct 18, 2013 11:30:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 2436 ms